Flutter Table with height and width constraints in different cells
I have this example table:
Table
Table(
             columnWidths: {
                0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(), 
                1: FlexColumnWidth(),
              },
              border: TableBorder.all(),
              children: [
                TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                        child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Text("Width"),
                    )),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                      child: Text("Height"),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )

The width of the second Container is indirectly set by the first Container because of the ColumnWidths.
The Problem is, that I need the first Container to take up all the available height in its cell
I tried wrapping the Container with:

Expanded
Flexible
IntrinsicHeight
Column

With the first two, an error occured ('Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget'), the second one did nothing and for the Column I tried putting two Elements inside the Column and set its MainAxis to spaceBetween but it did... nothing...
